# How to add a field which is an array of different models

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

We defined in TYPO3 9.5 this field in a model:

```
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News>
     * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\ORM\Lazy
     */
    protected $txIctivigoNoticesFrom;

    /**
     * Get notices from
     *
     * @return \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News[]
     */
    public function getTxIctivigoNoticesFrom()
    {
        return $this->txIctivigoNoticesFrom;
    }

    /**
     * Set notices from
     *
     * @param \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News[] $txIctivigoNoticesFrom
     */
    public function setTxIctivigoNoticesFrom($txIctivigoNoticesFrom)
    {
        $this->txIctivigoNoticesFrom = $txIctivigoNoticesFrom;
    }
```

But now we want to allow this is an array of not only news records, but `pages` and `sys_file_metadata` records as well. How could we achieve that?
We tried to instantiate an abstract entity between <>, but it's not possible.

TCA field is defined properly as a `group` type, and it saves relations to these three tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-to-use functionality in extbase to resolve such mixed references into objects. In the database field, the content is a comma separated list of identifiers, which are of the form `TABLENAME_UID`, like `tt_content_1670,tt_content_1672,pages_123`. So your only choice would be to receive those values as string(s) and then load the objects yourself.

With this solution, keep in mind, that **there are no default extbase models** for the core elements like `tt_content`, `page` and so on. So you will either have to use something like `https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Model/TtContent.php` and `https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Repository/TtContentRepository.php` and/or write the corresponding models and repositories yourself!

I you don't need extbase objects, but just the plain database data for some reason, you can also load this [directly from the database](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/BasicCrud/Index.html).